# checking a word in a text and if it matched a dictionary key add to the value of that key

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have a text stored in a string variable like so

```
r= '4"3/4 cutting head on location as part of the contract with NOV'
```

I have a dictionary like so

```
d={'4"3/4':0}
```

I want to check if the key value matches any of data in the string and if true add one to the value of the mentioned key

Comment: You can use the `in` operator. `if key in r:`

Comment: how do I update the value

Comment: also how am i referencing the mentioned dictionary especially if you have more than one dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can make an updated dictionary:

```
d = {key: value + 1 if key in r else value
   for key, value in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key,value in d.items():
    if key in r:
        d[key]=value+1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there a way to do it without for loop, Yes in this example its simple but I am dealing with a lot of data is there a way to compare multiple keys in a file and increase the value for all keys matched in the text.